# Illustration of Liouville theorem

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde

In a class, I'll teach the Liouville theorem for harmonic functions with finite Dirichlet integral. What kind of illustrations can I use to elucidate the meaning and proof of the theorem?

Note that a proof of this result is for example on MathOverflow: [Prove Liouville theorem without using mean value property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380958/prove-liouville-theorem-without-using-mean-value-property)

Comment: does this help? https://mathoverflow.net/q/100750/11260

Comment: Another point of view is to use spherical harmonics;  $u(r,\theta)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(r) \psi_k(\theta)$ and then you can solve for $a_k$ to get $$a_k(r) =C_k r^{\beta_k^+}+ D_k r^{\beta_k^-}$$ and then try and show $C_k=D_k=0$ (here the equation for $a_k$  is Euler and so $\beta_k^+,\beta_k^-$ are the associated roots and $ \psi_k(\theta)$ are the eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $S^{N-1}$.)